# Would my fridge wear or be damaged when I unplug it for a week?

Tags: refrigerator

My fridge is fairly 3 years old ([Here](http://www.samsung.com/ph/consumer/home-appliances/refrigerators/top-mount-freezer/RT22FARBDSA/TC) is the model of my fridge) and I am usually going to be at work area for the week and do not get home until Friday night. I do not put much food in my fridge, only enough to get me through the weekend.

I am hesitant of unplugging the fridge when I leave the house every week then plugging it back when I get home. What are the pros and cons of doing this, besides conserving energy? Would this do harm to my fridge overtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning: A refrigerator unplugged with the door closed will become a **factory of disgusting mold**.

The cure is to leave the door open.  However, it is impossible to keep other people from closing the door the moment they see it open.

We have 4 fridges at a lodge, which we unplug to save electricity.   Every single time I unplug a fridge and block the door open, I return to find the door closed and the inside of the fridge a disgusting nightmare.  When I have asked these people "why mess with it", they said either habit, or that it was sticking out, or that it merely offended their sense of order.

Electromechanically, the fridge won't care.  It will save ocmpressor wear, and also energy (though not as much as you think on a newer Energy Star model..)

In fact, the off-grid solar folks have stopped recommending super custom 12V fridges with 6” thick foam walls, and just say to choose well among the readily available Energy Star models,  and run it off an inverter.

Answer (score 1):

You will wear out the outlet before you harm the refrigerator.

However, it may be better to simply turn the setting dial to lowest (warmest) and leave the refrigerator running plugged in. It'll rarely run, and it'll keep the unit from collecting moisture and growing mildew.

Answer (score 1):

Unplugging a refrigerator will not harm it.  However, if there are bacteria or molds within, those tend to flourish in a room temperature refrigerator unless it is kept very dry.

- You could relax the temperature setting so that it does not run as much but yet keeps the temperature at (say) 50 °F/10 °C to reduce the rate of biology experiment growth.
- Or you could turn it off and prop the door open so that it stays dry.
- Or you could just leave it running normally.  Really, how much electricity does it use if the door is not opened?